# How to read and write binary data as plist or zip?

Tags: python, encoding, binary, plist

`f.pk` is basically a container of base64 + zip which I need to import in Python and extract. The zip file is `p.plist`, so `f.pk = path + name + data` of `p.plist`.

I can't find any working encoding for `open()` or `codecs.open()` to open it as a str and save the output. I always have a generated `output.plist` which is different than the original.

Encodings I have already used include ASCII; UTF-x; Latin_1; ISO-x;

```
import codecs, os

with open('f.pk', 'r', encoding='Latin_1') as f:
    f_open = f.read()

with codecs.open('f.pk', 'r', encoding='zip') as f:
    f_open = f.read()

f2=f_open[3:] #SKIP DUMMY PART
f3=f2.split('-DATA-')
f4=f3[1].split('-COMMENT-')

with open('output.plist', 'w') as f:
    print(f_out, file=f)
```

> `original.plist = 5e03964972def5b83880397b7377e6d1aea33e2b`
>   `output.plist = 6473aea0ae8bc75a04859effe1ee366de4cdd2d2`

I have deep analyzed both files:
[image: both files] with no success.

Comment: Have you tried operating on the file at byte level?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I don't want bytes as output so I must find the same encoding of zip, plist and other unknown (I'm currently looking up this code in zipfile.py).

Comment: "The property list is in binary format and has no textual representation.  To see a textual representation, choose a different property list format using the Change Format submenu located in the Operations menu."

This is exactly what I'm trying to do, read and write binary format as str. If I try to write a json format instead of plist, my application won't recognize it.

Comment: if you want to read/write binary though, you have to operate in binary mode, i.e. `open(some_file, 'rb') as bin_file`. It'll give you a `bytes` type yeah, but you can use byte-strings to do your splits then.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.pk', 'rb') as f:
    f_open = f.read()

# do something with bytes here

with open('p.temp', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(f_bytes, f) # temp file

# reload temp file
with open("p.temp", 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

# skip encodings and skip unwanted bytes
data = data[4:-3]

# save it
with open('p.plist', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

os.remove('p.temp')
```